# How JSTL tags evaluated in JSF 2.1 for the below

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the below Test.xhtml where i can select mode as Sea/Air. I don't want to load the all the 4 pages(Page1.xhtml, Page2.xhtml, Page3.xhtml, Page4.xhtml) into the jsf view tree. In my scenario, mode once selected and saved that can not be changed to other mode. The saved mode will be shown as view mode. Since at any point of time i need only 2 files (Page1.xhtml, Page2.xhtml (or) Page3.xhtml, Page4.xhtml)... I am using the  JSTL  tag handler for dynamic including the pages. the below thing is working fine. But i am not able to understand how the rendering working.

**Test.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head><title>JSF And JSTL</title>
<link href="../css/styles.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div align="center">
<h:form id="form1">

<h:panelGrid  columns="2">
<h:outputLabel value="Select Mode"/>

    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectPageId" value="#{testBean.selectedMode}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sea" itemValue="sea" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Air" itemValue="air" />

    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="pageGroup"/>    

    </h:selectOneMenu>


</h:panelGrid>

   <h:panelGroup id="pageGroup">

    <c:if test="#{'sea' eq testBean.selectedMode}">
        <ui:include src="Page1.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="Page2.xhtml" />
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="#{'air' eq testBean.selectedMode}">
        <ui:include src="Page3.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="Page4.xhtml" />
    </c:if>
 </h:panelGroup>


</h:form>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**TestBean.java**

```
package com.test;


@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped 
public class TestBean {

    private String selectedMode;

    public String getSelectedMode() {
        return selectedMode;
    }

    public void setSelectedMode(String selectedMode) {
        this.selectedMode = selectedMode;
    }

}
```

**Updated Again**

Please help to clarify the below.

When i send a request first time to access the `Test.xhtml`, the jsf view (`UIViewRoot`) gets created. Since `testBean.selectedMode` by default is null.. this created view would not contain any component details of `<c:if>` and `<ui:include>` which are inside of `<h:panelGroup id="pageGroup">`.

After that when i send a second request(ajax postback) by selecting the mode as **sea**, the `UIViewRoot` gets created again for the request in the **Restore View Phase**. While `UIViewRoot` creation for this request in Restore View Phase, the tag handlers(`<c:xxx>, <f:xxx>, <ui:include>`) will get executed. 
Since the selected value 'sea' will be updated to model(`TestBean.java`) only in **Update Model Values Phase**, in the Restore View Phase the EL `#{testBean.selectedMode}` will be evaluated to null.
So in my example Test.xhtml page the both tag handlers (`<c:if test="#{'sea' eq testBean.selectedMode}">` and `<c:if test="#{'air' eq testBean.selectedMode}">`) will be evaluated to false. So the `UIViewRoot` does not contain any information related to the components inside `<h:panelGroup id="pageGroup">`.

Even though the `UIViewRoot` does not contain the components information inside the `<h:panelGroup id="pageGroup">`, How JSF able to render the included pages(`<ui:include src="Page1.xhtml" />,<ui:include src="Page2.xhtml" />`) successfully?

I am not sure how JSF rendering happening here. While Rendering, Is JSF re-creating the component tree for the particular rendering part(`<h:panelGroup id="pageGroup">`).?

**Note:** The example is working fine when i select mode as sea/air. The corresponding parts are rendering correctly.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You basically said there's no problem with the code? You're not clear on how this fails and/or what exactly you didn't understand. How taghandlers (thus not only JSTL, but also `<ui:include>`) work is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the reply. updated the question. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm blocked at 1st phrase already. JSF doesn't store `UIViewRoot` in session at all. It's basically request scoped and recreated on every request. Only the UI component state is stored in view scope (which is in turn stored in session in case of server side state saving) and restored into the newly created `UIViewRoot` on every postback. I didn't read the remainder as this is likely based on the first misassumption.

Comment: @BalusC, sorry for the late response. busy with urgent tasks. Thanks for the reply that corrected my misunderstanding about UIViewRoot. Update the question again. Pls. help to understand.